# ValueError with 'MatMul' in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie in Tensorflow. I just started working on this machine learning techonlogy from **TensorFlow official website** only.I am trying to implement **Softmax Regressions** but getting following  errors.

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 784 and 10 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,784], [10,784].

Here is the complete code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,784]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Here is the output I am getting:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with the definition of `x` one training sample will be a vector (x1, ...., x784), and the number of lines of `x` is given by the number of samples in a batch. With this in mind, the 'interesting' dimension is the number of columns, not the number of rows, as one might expect. Therefore, the vector `x` is multiplied from the left to the weight matrix `W`, resulting in a vector of shape (num_samples_per_batch, 10). In order to perform this multiplication from the left, you will have to switch the arguments of `W` as follows:

```
W=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
```

By the way: `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` expects unscaled logits (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), so you should not perform a `tf.nn.softmax()` before using this option. Therefore, I think it would be better to change

```
y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
```

to

```
y=tf.matmul(x,W)+b
```

and

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
```

to

`correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y),1), tf.argmax(y_,1))`.

This is the example with the modifications:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/",one_hot=True)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
W=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
# y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b

y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(y),1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(10, 784)'

Comment: You have a typo, it should be 10, not 100.

Comment: This is the error I am getting now. I think what you said has worked for me but partially.

Comment: Could you please add a comment containing the line of your code where the error occures?

Comment: Thanks @ml4294, I think you were right.I just got the running code.

Comment: But, even y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b) is working fine.

Comment: This might work well in this case, but using two softmax operations before calculating the cross entropy might turn out to be a bad idea if you are dealing with other data sets or network structures.